# Database size estimation tool

Tags: sql, filesize

Is there a tool for estimating the size of a database?

I am looking for such a tool, which I can input the estimated tables, row size, data types, indexes and other variables to give me a clue about the size of a yet-non-existing database.

I know MS Sql Server Books Online has a good documentation on how to estimate but I don't want to end up coding it :)

Comment: Oracle defines [DBA_SEGMENTS](http://www.ss64.com/orad/DBA_SEGMENTS.html) where you can check the allocated bytes for a table. It can be much greater than the value suggested by rownum*rowsize as described [here](http://oracleplz.blogspot.com/2006/02/size-of-table-in-bytes.html).

Comment: thanks, but I am not looking for the size of an existing database

Comment: I wrote an application to automate production of a spreadsheet that estimates future size of a database based on (user entered) number of rows per table. See http://lucid-nonsense.co.uk/?page_id=456 Might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase PowerDesigner is able to calculate database size from the model, requiring you only to estimate row numbers for each table.